# JSF - How can I take full control of a deployed managed bean if I want to troubleshoot?

Tags: java

I was given a URL that returns a name of person based on an unique id parameter (rest web service).

When I entered below url to a browser I was able to get expected name wrapped in json format via GET method. If I enter "id=1234" then name comes back as "DaeYoung". However it has to be https instead of http so that I have to download a CA cert from the server and import it to my browser otherwise it won't work.

```
https://[host:port]/fooService/queryName?id=1234
```

What I want to accomplish is create a managed bean that makes rest ws call in JSF (2.x) web application. First I ran a test code from a standalone Java class below from eclipse IDE to verify if I could get name value back. And yes, I was able to get expected name back.

However I had to add a CA cert from the server (rest ws service provider) to a local Java_Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts file and include HostnameVerifier in the code otherwise I would get java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx found.

```
public void findName() throws Exception {
    HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() 
    {
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            // ip address of rest service provider
            if (hostname.equals(127.0.0.1)) 
                return true;
            return false;
        }
    });     

    String url = "https://[host:port]/fooService/queryOIN";
    String query = "id=1234";
    String charset = "utf-8";
    URLConnection conn = new URL(url + "?" + query).openConnection();       
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
    InputStream in = conn.getInputStream();
    String name = IOUtils.toString(in,charset);
    System.out.println("name=" + name);
}
```

Now when I put above code into a bean and deployed a web app into an app server (websphere), I observed two events.

```
1. with a valid id "1234" provided, name "DaeYoung" expected however return value was empty string
2. no exception was thrown with above condition which I expected
```

I was tailing system log file but nothing abnormal behaviors are thrown.

My questions is...

```
How can I troubleshoot or verify above code running inside of the app server in order to grasp what is happening inside of findName() method?
```

Comment: Setup remote debugging for your app server on a particular port  and set up a debug configuration of 'remote java application' listening on that port. Then you can just debug like normal.

Comment: @James Scott Tayler: Thank you for your advice. I was able to run debug mode following this thread (http://www.mkyong.com/websphere/remote-debugging-with-eclipse-websphere-7/)

Comment: how is this jsf related? Or java-se? and why the 'exception' tag if you explicitly state there is **no** exception?

Comment: reason1) this web app is jsf reason 2) exceptional behavior was INDEED happening but I was not able to log/trace it. James Scott Tayler recommendation and the link I found I was able to debug in eclipse IDE and found where the pressure was lied AND be able to implement log (JUL).

Comment: 2: I removed the tag and please remove all non relevant info from the Q.. 1: Sure, but it is using a certain container/engine to. Why did you not add that? And it is using [tag:energy], why not add that tag. There is no indication in code the question of any JSF relation. Plain java code calling a webservice returning nothing is not JSF related, not even if it is used in a managed bean.

Comment: I removed jsf tag. Thank you for your advice.